# What is the best pattern for filling RecyclerView after retrieving a list from Realm?

Tags: android, realm

I'm using MVVC pattern where, on my Controller, I retrieve a list of objects in a thread other than Main. After that, I notice my view to update the RecyclerView with the newly retrieved objects this time in the Main thread.

Frequently I receive the exception that says that Realm managed objects cannot be manipulated outside the thread where they were created - since they were created in a thread on Controller and added on Main thread. This leads to errors trying to update the list whenever a object is added/removed or if the entire list is refreshed.

What is the best approach for using Realm in these situations?

Comment: https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters/blob/master/adapters/src/main/java/io/realm/RealmRecyclerViewAdapter.java

Comment: Still I'm getting Realm accessed from incorrect thread when using the pattern described on the question

Comment: Stop sending managed RealmObjects across threads then, and rely on the answer provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This leads to errors trying to update the list whenever a object is added/removed or if the entire list is refreshed.

Use **RealmRecyclerViewAdapter** (on the UI thread) which automatically manages a `OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener` which notifies the adapter when a change occurs to the dataset (by any write on any thread).

See the docs: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#adapters